# Jenkins: "Waiting for the completion of my_job"

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins which needs parameters and it gets called from different places.

Unfortunately I only see this in the jenkins GUI:

> Waiting for the completion of **my_job**
>
> (delay ...)
>
> **my_job** #21869 completed. Result was SUCCESS

The first line has a hyperlink to the general page of this job.
The second has a hyperlink to the particular instance of this job.

Is there a way to get the hyperlink to the particular job in the first line, too?

Background: I see the second line after the delay (after the job has finished).

Screenshot:

[image: jenkins-screenshot]

Comment: Do you see the above message in the _called_ job's UI? Can you please paste the screenshot? Are the _calling_ jobs and _called_ job all freestyle/pipeline/mix of both?

Comment: I added a screenshot. It would be nice if there could the link to #10988 in the "wating for ...." line, too.

Comment: Check how the job is called from the existing one, if it's done with curl you should also add the step to read the jobqueue to record additional line with the running job url. Mostly in your case it's just waiting for the job completion and updates the console with the completed job link

Comment: @guettli: I was thinking if i could at least replicate the job's set up but this info is not getting me anywhere. :(